# Android : How to manage fragments in a single Activity?

Tags: android, fragment

I wonder whether I can manage fragments like Activity.
I implemented tab function with fragment(in fact, I couldn't get result from `startActivityForResult` using `TabHost`), and I wanna call each fragment when tab menu selected saving its previous view like using intent with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`. Whenever I replace fragment, program always create new fragment.
Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

ps. I tried to use `savedInstanceState`, but Bundle only provides `putInt`, `putString`, `putBundle`, etc. Is it possible to save view or other objects?

@PatrickBoos
Here is my code. After declare `FragmentManager fm` and `FragmentTransaction ft`,

```
AFragment fragment = AFragment.getInstance();
if (!fragment.isAdded())
    ft.replace(res, fragment, tag);
ft.commit();
```

and AFragment.newInstance() is implemented as,

```
AFragment mThis;
public static AFragment getInstance() {
    if (mThis == null)
        mThis = new AFragment();
    return mThis;
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code of where you do the replace fragment? I guess you are the one always creating a new fragment. Try to save references to the created tabs and use them when replacing fragments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using something similar to the code below to reuse a fragment

```
ContactListFragment contactListFragment = 
     (ContactListFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ContactList");
if(contactListFragment == null){
contactListFragment = new ContactListFragment();
}
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, contactListFragment,"ContactList";
ft.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention. But sadly, it doesn't work. It throws IllegalStateException since the fragment cannot be added twice(error message said 'Fragment already added').